# jQuery Mobile - gray dead space (image)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

[image: Gray dead space]

Link to my app: http://gizeto.com/app_orange/index.html

I don't understand why this occurs on `orientationchange`. Does anybody recognize this?

Comment: it seems like the height of your template is short for vertical, it's ok if I flip the phone on horizontal. How are you handling this? Can you post some of the html?

Comment: I'm not handling any transition from portait to landscape, I thought jQuery handled that? All I've done is created a theme from themeroller and implemented it. The background is just a color I guess, no image or such.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in your case, but I'd look into `orientationchange` event from jquery mobile and modify your sizing then.. Here's a good sample: http://www.roccles.com/?p=140

Comment: Why isn't that possible in my case? Just curious ;)

Comment: who knows :) sometimes the managers just say no to obvious things

Comment: I think it's iscroll that's causing the issue, COuld you use jQM's scrollview? http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

Comment: @PhillPafford That doesn't work for me. I can scroll down but every time I scroll my navigation menu fade away, then when I stop scroll the navigation menu it fades in again. I don't like that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you are using iScroll for your scrollable areas. If this is the case then you will need to update the iScroll instance whenever a `resize` or `orientationchange` event fires on the `window` object:

```
var myScroll = new iScroll();

//you can change `resize` to `orientationchange` if you only want to support mobile devices
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    myScroll.refresh();
});
```

*Source: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4#refreshmethod*

This should keep the iScroll area the correct dimensions when the size of the document changes. If the iScroll container (in your case this is the `data-role="content"` element) still doesn't update it's height then you may need to do that manually:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="content"]').height('{HEIGHT HERE}px');
    myScroll.refresh();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When doing what you proposed I ended up with http://gizeto.com/app_orange - the background seems to take over everything. As you can see in my code I make the bind inside my page-div with $(document).delegate('#start', 'pageinit', function() { }); Is that correct? I'm doing something wrong but we seem to drive on the right road...

Comment: @FernandoRedondo When I go to your site I get this error: `iscroll.js:18 -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null`. I believe you need to reference your container element when you create the iScroll instance: `var myScroll = new iScroll('content');//this will target the data-role="content" element`. Also, note that iScroll 4.x.x is out and is preferable over 3.x.x.

Comment: @FernandoRedondo Also there is an option called `checkDOMChanges` that if set to `true` should automatically update the iScroll instance when the DOM changes. I have not used it but it looks promising: http://cubiq.org/iscroll#iscroll-syntax

Comment: Wow, I now noticed that you can't scroll for example in the middle of the text, but you have to tap in the right area of the display to scroll the content. Do you now how I can make iScroll4 scroll where ever I tap in the content? Also, my footer still fades out and fades in when I release the scroll. This was the behavior I wanted to avoid with iScroll :)

Comment: Now I can scroll in the middle of the text. I guess it's because i put the data-iscroll="enable" in my data-role="content" instead of data-role="page" as I did before. But the iscroll scrolls the whole page anyway, it scrolls away the header and the footer still... I just want't it to scroll the data-role="content" so my header and footer will be fixed.

Comment: Everything seems to be solved now. http://gizeto.com/app_orange, I have to use position:fixed to get the header and footer fixed. I know this isn't supported everywhere but they will solve this in 1.1: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3216